# What determines the trophy awarded after a tour?

Tags: cruisn-blast

What determines the type of trophy you receive at the end of a tour in Cruis'n Blast?

For example, in one tour I placed 1st on three races and 3rd on the last race, but I was still awarded a gold trophy. Would I have been knocked down to a silver trophy if I'd placed 4th instead of 3rd on the last race?